# iOS 6: adding non-auto-layout view to auto-layout view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I need to show a generic error view across all screens, I've got the sliding error view component which does not use auto-layout, now I'm using auto-layout for all my new projects, and when I add the error view as subview to my view controllers view with animation (ie sliding up from bottom of screen), I cannot see anything.

My thought is that the view controller's view has auto-layout constraints, and it does not know how to position and layout the error view which is not auto-layouted.

So I wonder what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: You should update your generic error view to use constraints.

Comment: Are you creating your error view in code or in Interface Builder?